# How to initially collapse expandable table rows

Tags: jquery, html

I have an expanding table row which is working however there are 2 things im not sure of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<table>
  <tr class="parent" id="row123">
    <td>People</td>
    <td>Click to Expand</td>        
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child-row123">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child-row123">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent')
        .css("cursor","pointer")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
        });
    $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- How do you ensure you collapse the rows at the beginning
- How do you
  perform a slideToggle effect when I have tried using this I get some
  odd results.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle recreating the issue?

Comment: You can change your selector to this: `tr[class^="child-"]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This

```
$('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
```

should probably be this:

```
$('tr[class^=child-]').children('td').hide();
```

Note the removed @.

For the slideToggle, use a div instead of table elements, which are notoriously troublesome in animations:

```
<td><div>People</div></td>

$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find('td > div').slideToggle();
});

$('tr[class^=child-]').children('td').children('div').hide();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0Lh5ozyb/1/)**

The selectors get a little more complicated with multiple child rows:

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function () {
        // slide up divs in all sibling rows
        $(this).siblings('tr[class^=child-]').find('div').slideUp();

        // define children as all trailing, sequential rows with 'child-' class
        var $children = $(this).nextUntil( $('tr').not('[class^=child-]') );

        // toggle those
        $children.find('td > div').slideToggle();
});

// initially hide all child rows (could also be done with CSS)
$('tr[class^=child-]').find('td > div').hide();
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0Lh5ozyb/12/)**

Comment: I tested this and it works but only if you have a single row . Ive updated jsfiddle to show this - http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/2/

Comment: Answer updated. I'd seriously consider a markup change to put child rows inside parent rows. Would dramatically simplify your scripting and would probably make your tables more accessible.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you coud put something explaining how it works as I also need to prevent click when clicking an input box.

Comment: I'll add some comments to help explain. Please ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: thanks i just need to remove the passing so its all flush when collapsed

Answer (score 1):

You can add an effect on the toggle action, for example 'slow'.

And for the collapse at the beggining you can select all simblings of the tr like:

```
$('tr.parent').siblings('[class^=child]').hide();
```

I made a working example:
Here's [a jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/taq8seso/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('tr[class^="child-"]').hide();
    $('tr.parent')
        .css("cursor","pointer")
        .click(function(){
            $('.child-'+$(this).attr("id"). slidetoggle();
        });
});
```